# Do I compile Ubuntu Source code on Red Hat System?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, compiling

If we install the Red Hat System then can we compile the other distros of linux on the Red Hat server system? If so, please provide me the tutorials and links.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to do. Do you want to install multiple distros on one computer? What does compiling have to do with it? If all you need is multiple operating systems on the same machine, try searching google for "dual boot".

Comment: What do you mean by compile? debian packages come in `.deb` format and fedora packages come in `.rpm` format. From what I understand, your question is more like can we use `.exe` file for installation in a red hat system, which obviously is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First If by that you mean creating a custom Ubuntu or other distros yes you can and this action is not entirely distro-specific (i.e in your case Redhat).
For that you could use two diffrerent approaches. Either use automation tools such as linuxcoe and other different tools or go native and start by LFS (Linux From Scratch). Either way you have three things to consider:

1. Your kernel
2. Your GUI
3. You distribution system

[Build your own distro](http://www.maketecheasier.com/6-tools-to-easily-create-your-own-custom-linux-distro/)

For the third option you could use other distros tools also (or write your own)

Or you meant to compile codes for other platforms which is something else and has more to do with your `make` and build environment and coding skills (writing config files for example). you code do it in Jail env. or Virtual machine if you like.

Or perhaps you meant to access other distros inside a running RedHat.
In this case what you should consider the most is the arch of the *Host* and *target* system.
This could be done by `chroot`ing. 
Consider that you have the live image of some distro in `/mnt/distro`.
first you should mount your `/proc` , `/dev` and `/sys` 
Then `chroot` to `/mnt/distro`.

```
mount -t proc proc /mnt/distro/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/distro/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/distro/dev
```

Then for `chroot`ing part you need to specify your environment completely to avoid problems in future.

```
chroot /mnt/distro /bin/env -i TERM=$TERM /bin/bash
```

Note: It is the base idea and the `path` and `env` would be different in your case

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and the most proper variant today is to install a target system as a virtual guest, using any kind of virtualization (from a simple `chroot` through `LXC` and up to `VirtualBox`, `VMWare`, etc.) and then use distro-specific native tools.

You should think of some cross compilation without virtualization under very extreme circumstances.